# No page number for TOC entry followed by entry deeper and same page

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, conditionals, etoc

Let's assume that my Introduction is Chapter 1 on page 1, with no sectioning.
And Chapter 2, Section 2.1 and Subsection 2.1.1 appear on page 3. And Subsection 2.1.2 and Section 2.2 and Section 2.3 appear on page 4...
Now I want the table of contents to look like this:

Chapter 1 Introduction . . . .  1

Chapter 2 Title

Section 2.1 Title

Subsection 2.1.1 Title . . . .  3

Subsection 2.1.2 Title . . . .  4

Section 2.2 Title . . . . . .  4

Section 2.3 Title . . . . . .  4

So the logic is that a sectioning entry doesn't show its page number if it is followed by one entry of deeper sectioning level on the same page.
Can it be done? For what it's worth I'm using etoc.

Comment: First, you don't know if there is a deeper level until later, but one could use the aux file for this.  You would have to modify \l@chapter, \l@section, etc to check, which also means modifying \@dottedtocline.  So, yes it can be done, but it would be a real pain to do.

Comment: I guess that the items on the same page will more or less always stay on the same page (even if the number of that page shifts due to changes within the whole text). So, perhaps you can add a switch to include/exclude page number in the toc.